# VPN with network manager (nm-applet) is not working

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, networkmanager

My university (TU Wien) offers a VPN in order to get an IP of the university network. The instruction on the university webpage says to install the packages `network-manager-gnome`, `network-manager-vpnc` and `vpnc` and also a screenshot with the correct settings is provided:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tuwien.ac.at](https://www.zid.tuwien.ac.at/fileadmin/files_kom/anleitungen/vpn/GnomeNetworkManager_vpnc_extern.png))</sub>

But when I try to connect, simple nothing happens. There is no error nor does anything else change. There is also no message on the command line (when starting the `nm-applet` there).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm at the same University. Setting up vpn was a pain, but finally I did just the same as you (on Debian Testing x64). For me that worked.

Comment: I really hope that's not a real group password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it's working now. I didn't change anything, but I rebooted my system several times. Maybe I forgot to do this the first time and restarting the network manager didn't suffice.

Answer (score 2):

`nm-applet` only talks to network-manager (over d-bus); messages of network-manager itself are sent to syslog, `tail -f /var/log/syslog` will show you what is going on while it is trying to connect:

```
Aug  4 12:01:59 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> Starting VPN service 'vpnc'...
Aug  4 12:01:59 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 10062
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' appeared; activating connections
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> VPN connection 'Something' (Connect) reply received.
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> VPN connection 'Something' (IP Config Get) reply received.
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> VPN Gateway: *******
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> Tunnel Device: tun0
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> Internal IP4 Address: 10.16.7.37
Aug  4 12:02:00 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> Internal IP4 Prefix: 20
...
Aug  4 12:02:01 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> Clearing nscd hosts cache.
Aug  4 12:02:01 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> VPN connection 'Something' (IP Config Get) complete.
Aug  4 12:02:01 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> Policy set 'Auto eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Aug  4 12:02:01 flux NetworkManager[1085]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 4
```

and so on. It is not always terribly informative (especially if VPNC authentication fails), but nevertheless useful.